# classic load balancer https acm issue

Tags: amazon-ec2, https, elastic-load-balancer, aws-certificate-manager

I have a website -- portaldevservices.com

The domain is managed by route 53 and works fine with http.

I have one ec2 instance.

I recently decided to move to https and put a load balancer in front of the ec2 instance.

From here I created a load balancer edited the A record and the Cname to the credentials of the load balancer. The health check is fine and the ec2 instance was added.

Using Amazon Certificate manager I created a cert and added it to the load balancer.

Here are some credentials/info:

When I try to access https://portaldevservices.com I get this:
[Website screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4Y6a.png)

[hosted zones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlXKy.png)

[load balancer port config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvlcn.png)

[load balancer basic config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4KBc.png)

[load balancer listener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RV5A5.png)

[acm certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRW6Y.png)

Thanks for the help. I'm a mobile dev so this is my first time really stepping into the backend world.

**Solved:**

Ok that was a lot easier than I thought. If anyone else experiences this issue all I had to do was add the "www." to the front of my A type

From portaldevservices.com -> www.portaldevservices.com

The https access now works well.

Comment: Looks like your certificate is for `www.portaldevservices.com`, and you are trying to open `portaldevservices.com `

Comment: Yes that's what someone suggested to me. I'm unable to make a cert omitting the www. (Or atleast it's been trying to validate for over 24 hrs)

Comment: 1) Domain names need to match, so that is the reason for the error. 2) Your hosted zone screenshot shows no CNAME record for `portaldevservices.com` cert validation; repeat the procedure and follow the instructions carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok that was a lot easier than I thought. If anyone else experiences this issue all I had to do was add the "www." to the front of my A type

From portaldevservices.com -> www.portaldevservices.com

The https access now works well.